# "??" bytes in Visual Studio disassembly view when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, disassembly

I'm currently using the disassembly view of VS to debug some C# code. There are some memory regions that look like this when both bytes and disassembly are shown:

```
24E2822A ??                   ?? ?? 
24E2822B ??                   ?? ?? 
24E2822C ??                   ?? ?? 
24E2822D FB                   sti  
24E2822E 2B 8B CE E8 9A 2A    sub         ecx,dword ptr [ebx+2A9AE8CEh]  
24E28234 1B 2D CC 00 B8 9D    sbb         ebp,dword ptr ds:[9DB800CCh]  
24E2823A DC 24 00             fsub        qword ptr [eax+eax]
```

I would have expected that the `??` corresponded to unmapped memory regions, however I've seen `call` instructions that point to these `??` regions. Attempting to use VS's step into functionality simply results in stepping over those calls. My next guess was that these were pre-JIT memory regions, but breaking in that area of the code multiple times in a row results in the same `??` in those areas.

What is Visual Studio trying to tell me about this memory region?

Comment: Memory regions can only allocated in 64k blocks and protected in 4k blocks. Such a 4k block should end in 0x...000, so it's not a non-committed/reserved memory block.

Comment: What happens if you attach another debugger, e.g. WinDbg and look at those addresses?

Comment: The disassembler got very buggy in VS2015, it doesn't properly update the view when the jitter generates code.  Some sort of caching bug.  You can get ahead somewhat with Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  That selects the old debugging engine, last used in VS2010.  It is much less buggy.  Beware that it generates addresses very differently, makes CALL and JMP addresses inaccurate.

Comment: @ThomasWeller attaching WinDbg to IISExpress.exe and going to the same offsets gives a similar ?? block.

Comment: @HansPassant managed debugging mode does seem like it's stepping into more calls correctly and I have yet to see any ?? blocks. The amount of disassembly it shows seems to be more localized- the view always starts at address 0 rather than what I assume were the absolute addresses from my original sample.

Based on that I wonder if I'm simply not able to scroll to where those ?? blocks were originally.

Comment: I still get this problem, how many years will it take for MS to fix this? This has annoyed me for years... [Edit] this is about c#, sorry, there's the same issue with the native C++ debugger, and not much info on the web]

Comment: Seems to be unreadable blocks....